# webseal virtual junction not forwarding packets to server

Tags: webseal

I have configured a Virtual Junction on Webseal with command:

> pdadmin sec_master> server task default-webseald-abkale2l virtual host create -t tcp -h abkale2l -p 7002 -v abkale2l:7002 -f vmachine1

I have WebSEAL server and application server on same machine.

when i hit url https://abkale2l:7002 i am expecting webseal will interrupt the package and throw an authentication challenge but not happening.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you get no error message with that? The correct syntax is `virtualhost`, instead of `virtual host`.

Comment: well I moved away from using Virtual junction. Finally decided on using a Slash junction (root level junction)

Comment: got the virtual junction working, added a entry in hosts file and created an interface in webseal instance